# Send data obtained from facebook with form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to send data to a PHP page from a HTML page. Data is acquired from a JavaScript variable.

**Scenario:**
I am trying to create a Facebook login page. I acquired data from a FB script and want to send a name to another PHP page. Here is a sample of my code:

**Obtain name FB script:**

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
var vv=response.name;
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + vv + '!';
});
```

Variable `vv` contains the value of the name.

I then try to send it with **this form**:

```
<form method="post" action="sample.php" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="<?php echo $vv; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="bar" /> 
    <a href="sample.php" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit(); return false;">Go to Home</a>
</form>
```

I then try to display the data in **Sample.php**:

```
<?php
echo $_POST["field1"];
?>
```

I think my form is missing something.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $_POST["field1"];`?

Comment: why you need return false; ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript variables are different than php variables. You need to put the login as input value and submit the form with javascript in order to get that variable in sample.php. Besides, I don't know how that javascript code works with those brackets. Here's how I think the code should go:

```
<form method="post" action="sample.php" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" id="responsename" />
    <input type="hidden" name="field2" value="bar" /> 

    <a href="sample.php" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit(); return false;">Go to Home</a>
</form>
```

Note that I put an `id` parameter on your input.

```
function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
        var input = document.getElementById('responsename');
        input.value = response.name;
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely what I wanted for this question ! Thank you so much . Your code works successfully ! :)